# display # of comments for a UserProfile in Django

Tags: django, comments, profile

How do I connect my UserProfile model to a User's Comments? In my UserProfileAdmin I would like to show # of comments for each User. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** My Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
                      ('M', _('Male')),
                      ('F', _('Female')))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I also would like to display the User's list of comments when viewing a UserProfile. Since I am using Django's built-in comment system, is there a shortcut to do this? Or do I have to do something like `Comments.objects.filter(user=user)` something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UserProfile.user.comment_comments.count()
```

should do it.

You could wrap this into a method on your profile model

```
def count_comments(self):
    if self.user:
        return self.user.comment_comments.count()
```

and add `count_comments` to the [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option in your ModelAdmin.

---

If you want to get the list of a user's comments you could tweak the method accordingly:

```
def get_comments(self):
    if self.user:
        return self.user.comment_comments.all()
```

Then you can do:

```
User.objects.get(pk=1).comment_comments.all()
```

or:

```
UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1).get_comments()
```

Comment: I just tried to add get_comments() to fields in UserProfileAdmin and I guess that's not allowed? I'm trying to display a list of the user's comments on the admin side. I know I can do that by filtering in Comments directly, but I thought I'd give it a try. EDIT: Apparently I'm wrong. I cannot filter by User in Comments, at least not on the default admin list dislpay for Comments.

Comment: Are you talking about the UserProfile changelist? Did you try adding get_comments (without the brackets) to list_display?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got the following error: `Exception Value: 
'UserProfileAdmin.fields' refers to field 'get_comments' that is missing from the form.` get_comments() is there and definitely works because I am using it in a template. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about the fields or the list_display (check the link in my answer) option? One modifies the fields in the change_list view, the other defines the fields in change_view of a single object. If was refering to list_display, but your error indicates that you added get_comments to fields.

Comment: I am talking about fields :) Not list_display. To clarify, I put count_comments() into list_display, and get_comments into fields. Fields leads to the view where you can edit the database entries. On a side note, how do I add a User column to Comment's list_display so I can at least sort and search comments by user? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While registering admin (or if you creating custom one) just use field something like `UserComments.filter(user).count()` Its hard to tell not knowing how your models look like. but the main idea is to direct that field to that specific user comments and use `.count()`. I could update my answer (or others would answer better) if you would provide more code.

UPDATE: sorry forgot the docs. For `.count()`: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count
for filters: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter
for registering admin: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: thanks for your answer! updated my question with code, and another question!